# How to install a downloaded free theme in magento 2?

Tags: installation, themes, magento2

I have just installed magento 2 in windows 10 , in xampp 127.0.0.1:8080 domain and by default it has a luma theme on it , i have downloaded a new theme called purity in .zip formate and since i am new to magento i have no idea how to install this theme? anyone please help me if you can, thank you

Comment: I suggest asking this on the [magento.se] site.

Answer (score 2):

1. Upload and decompress the theme file into webroot folder in your site
2. Run the command script via SSH or terminal app of your site:
        php -f bin/magento setup:upgrade (be sure that you are at magento home folder)
3. If theme show in list themes. Go to Stores > Configuration > Design > choose design "Your theme". Save the change. The step will apply the theme for frontend of your store.

Comment: From Magento 2.1, the configuration for theme is available at Content -> Design -> Configuration section in the admin

Answer (score 2):

You can move your downloaded theme on your project `app/code` & `app/design` folders & fire all the necessary commands like below:

```
sudo php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```